# Pass values of variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I writing app for UWP

I have PCL where I writing methods for downloading json from OpenWeather

Here is code.

```
 public class WeatherRepositoryForUWP
    {
        private string url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&units=imperial&APPID=274c6def18f89eb1d9a444822d2574b5";

        public async void DownloadWeather()
        {
            var json = await FetchAsync(url);
            Debug.WriteLine(json.ToString());

        }
        public async Task<string> FetchAsync(string url)
        {
            string jsonString;

            using (var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
            {
                //var stream = httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url).Result;
                var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);

                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();


            }


            return jsonString;
        }

        // Classes for parser
        public class Coord
        {
            public double lon { get; set; }
            public double lat { get; set; }
        }

        public class Weather
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string main { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string icon { get; set; }
        }

        public class Main
        {
            public double temp { get; set; }
            public int pressure { get; set; }
            public int humidity { get; set; }
            public double temp_min { get; set; }
            public int temp_max { get; set; }
        }

        public class Wind
        {
            public double speed { get; set; }
            public int deg { get; set; }
        }

        public class Clouds
        {
            public int all { get; set; }
        }

        public class Sys
        {
            public int type { get; set; }
            public int id { get; set; }
            public double message { get; set; }
            public string country { get; set; }
            public int sunrise { get; set; }
            public int sunset { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public Coord coord { get; set; }
            public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
            public string @base { get; set; }
            public Main main { get; set; }
            public int visibility { get; set; }
            public Wind wind { get; set; }
            public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
            public int dt { get; set; }
            public Sys sys { get; set; }
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int cod { get; set; }
        }
    }

}
```

Also I have GUI where user write it city and it writing o variable when he\she taps button.

Here is code for this:

```
 private void city_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string city_name;
        city_name = city_text.Text;
        Debug.WriteLine(city_name);
    }
```

I need to take value from city_name and pass it to class in PCL and write to  string variable.

How I can do this?

Thank's for help!

Comment: So you want to retrieve weather information for a custom city, not London only?

Comment: What is PCL, what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Yes, you're right. @botond.botos

Comment: PCL - Portable Class Library @mybirthname

Answer (score 2):

In order to be able to retrieve weather information for a custom city, you need to change your `WeatherRepositoryForUWP` class the following way:

```
public class WeatherRepositoryForUWP
{
    private string urlFormat = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={0}&units=imperial&APPID=274c6def18f89eb1d9a444822d2574b5";

    public async Task<string> DownloadWeather(string city)
    {
        return await FetchAsync(string.Format(urlFormat, city));
    }

    // Rest of class remains unchanged....
}
```

Then, in your click event handler, you have to do the following:

```
private void city_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string city_name;
    city_name = city_text.Text;
    var weatherService = new WeatherRepositoryForUWP();
    string weatherData = weatherService.DownloadWeather(city_name).Result;
}
```

Comment: Thank's, I will try